# Fit listview cell to content after Downloading an image

Tags: android, listview, height, cell, picasso

I'm currently working on a view which would display different images downloaded from online, the images could have a different ratio but would still have a higher width than height.

Unfortunately for the moment my ListView cell has a defined height even though I put wrap_content in the cell layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_elem_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using Picasso to download the image

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipe_element_view, parent, false);


        Recipe item = getItem(position);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getPictureUrl())
                .into((ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_elem_img));
        return rowView;
    }
```

and here's the result:

[image: NO DESCRIPTION]

I basically want to get rid of the yellow part for every image no matter their aspect ratio.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'd try consulting the docs for the library - it is well documented